# Transforming list obtained via strsplit to merge common categories

Tags: r, string, list, strsplit

I have a list resembling the one below:

```
# Initial object
vec <- c("levelA-1", "levelA-2", "levelA-3",
         "levelB-1", "levelB-2", "levelB-3")
lstVec <- strsplit(x = vec, split = "-")
```

I would like to arrive at a list of the following structure:

```
lstRes <- list(levelA = list(1:3),
               lvelB = list(1:3))
```

## Notes

The list has the following characteristics:

- First level elements are transformed into distinct lists
- Second level elements created via `strsplit` are elements of those lists

Answer (score 5):

this suffices:

```
mat <- do.call(rbind, lstVec)    
result <- split(mat[,2], mat[,1])
```

the `do.call` and `rbind` stack the result of `lstVec` by row into a matrix (thanks to G. Grothendieck for pointing out this is not a data frame), then the `split` split `mat[,2]` by `mat[,1]`.

as Aaron says, ti is a little odd that you want nested list. but you can get it

```
lapply(result, as.list)
```

i am not sure how good `rbind` is. but another way to obtain `mat` is

```
mat <- matrix(unlist(lstVec), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: To have each element in lists (which may not actually be what the OP wants, it's a little odd), you'll also have to convert each element to a list with lapply.

Comment: It's also helpful to add a little commentary explaining what this does. Welcome to SO!